# Does IloCplex::Param::MIP::Display parameter restrict information displayed related to repairing singularity and Markowitz Tolerance?

Tags: cplex, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

The warnings that I henceforth refer to are as follows; repairing basis singularity, added to 1 column super-basic list and Markowitz threshold set to 0.3.

Will toggling the IloCplex::Param::MIP::Display parameter value between 2 (default) and 5 switch off and on the display of above-mentioned warnings in the log file respectively. Assume that the above-mentioned issues arise in the LP sub-problems inside the branch-cut and bound tree.

Answer (score 0):

The "Repairing basis singularity" and "Markowitz threshold set to" messages are controled by the [IloCplex::Param::Simplex::Display](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/SimDisplay.html) parameter (aka `CPX_PARAM_SIMDISPLAY`). I'm not sure about the other message ("added to 1 column super-basic list"), which version of CPLEX are you using?

As mentioned in the documentation for [IloCplex::Param::MIP::Display](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/MIPDisplay.html):

> A setting of 5 additionally generates entries for the LP subproblems,
>   also according to the setting of the parameter to control the simplex
>   iteration information display (SimDisplay, CPX_PARAM_SIMDISPLAY).

So, when you toggle the value of `IloCplex::Param::MIP::Display` between 2 and 5, it should control whether the warnings you mentioned are displayed or not **if** the value of `IloCplex::Param::Simplex::Display` is greater than 0.

Comment: Using cplex 12.7.1. Haven't touched the IloCplex::Param::Simplex::Display parameter setting. I ask this question because for lot of instances I get no warnings when I run them using IloCplex::Param::MIP::Display = 2. For the same instances if IloCplex::Param::MIP::Display = 5 then I start seeing this warnings. Just want to make sure that these warnings are not affected by the MIP display parameter.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to make sure that the warnings are always shown? Or, do you want to make sure that they are never shown?

Comment: Trying to figure out whether there is a bug in Cplex. Just wanted to make sure toggling the display parameters is not affecting the above mentioned messages.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I finally reached this conclusion. Irrespective of the IloCplex::Param::Simplex::Display parameter setting if the IloCplex::Param::MIP::Display = 5 then it displays the 'repairing basis singularity' and 'added to 1 column super-basic list' even for LP sub-problems.

In contrast, setting the IloCplex::Param::MIP::Display = 2 (default) display the basis singularity related issues only for the root node LP.

Finally, Markowitz Tolerance message gets displayed for both IloCplex::Param::MIP::Display = 5 and IloCplex::Param::MIP::Display = 2.

Just putting it out there in case anyone requires it in the future. Additionally, these messages might point towards numerical issues in the data.

Comment: Is it possible to share the model that you get this behavior with by editing your question? If not, can you share the model (export to SAV format) with me at `rkersh at us dot ibm dot com`?